# SQLite Exception syntax error near "s"

Tags: android, sql

Really sorry if this is trivial but I have tried very hard to find the error in this method and am quite new to sql. Not sure what is going wrong here. Would be really grateful for help

public List getAllTasksbyLocation(String address) {

```
    List<Task> tasklist = new ArrayList<Task>();
     String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TASKS + " tskTble, "
                + TABLE_LOCATIONS + " locTble, " + TABLE_TLRELATIONSHIP
                + " tlRelation WHERE locTble." + KEY_MARKER_ADDRESS + " = '"
                + address + "'" + " AND locTble." + KEY_ID + " = "
                + "tlRelation." + KEY_LOCATION_ID + " AND tskTble." + KEY_ID
                + " = " + "tlRelation." + KEY_TASK_ID;

        // insert log here

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to the list

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Task task = new Task();
                task.setID(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
                task.setTaskTitle(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TASK_TITLE)));
                task.setTaskDifficulty(c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex(KEY_TASK_DIFFICULTY)));

                task.setDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TASK_DATE)));

                task.setTime(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TASK_TIME)));
                task.setNotes(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TASK_NOTES)));
                task.setNotification(c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex(KEY_TASK_NOTIFICATION)));

                tasklist.add(task);
            } while (c.moveToNext());

        }
        return tasklist;

}
```

```
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prototype3/com.example.prototype3.map.TaskList_Map}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tasks tskTble, locations locTble, tasks_and_locations tlRelation WHERE locTble.address = '56 Pritchatt's Rd, Birmingham, United Kingdom' AND locTble.id = tlRelation.location_id AND tskTble.id = tlRelation.task_id
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tasks tskTble, locations locTble, tasks_and_locations tlRelation WHERE locTble.address = '56 Pritchatt's Rd, Birmingham, United Kingdom' AND locTble.id = tlRelation.location_id AND tskTble.id = tlRelation.task_id
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1118)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:691)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1436)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1375)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at com.example.prototype3.database.DatabaseHelper.getAllTasksbyLocation(DatabaseHelper.java:229)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at com.example.prototype3.map.TaskList_Map.loadTasksToMap(TaskList_Map.java:134)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at com.example.prototype3.map.TaskList_Map.onCreate(TaskList_Map.java:85)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
02-10 00:18:24.785: E/AndroidRuntime(29232):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Pritchard's road has a single quote, which closes the quoted string it is in.  You need to escape quotes first..

Comment: You have an extra ' symbol in that address. You will need to escape it.

Comment: '56 Pritchatt's Rd, Birmingham here the error , :) try to read the exception before asking , you will get it  :)

Comment: thanks guys, really appreciate the feedback. I didn't think my input address was at fault and was puzzled by my sql statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The address that you want to insert it into your table contains a  " ' "  (**apostrophe** )so , there is an error when the request is excuted : the address (String )

> ***' 56 Pritchatt '***    s Rd, Birmingham, United Kingdom '

the address for the system is *56 Pritchatt* , the rest caused an error

You should not use an address (or string ) with **apostrophe** in a request .